# Feature Request: Why can't we favorite answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, bookmarks

I have a feature request why can't we favorite answers? Would it be a problem?

Comment: There's quite a simple "work around": favorite the question that has an answer you consider a favorite answer.  Simple as that.

Comment: @amWhy To be fair, this is a little unwieldy for questions with lots of answers. More significantly, it could be fun for the *answerer* to see that their answer is being favorited. I don't think this rises to the level of a feature request (although if it took zero effort to implement I would want it), but I do think it's not fully redundant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sometimes you need to capture techinque, cause how you address a problem could be unique and helpful.

Comment: You're right, @Noah.  I didn't mean to be dismissive, Enlightened Funky.